# Rviz2 Custom panel plugin: "Could not load library dlopen error, undefined symbol: _ZTV10Rviz2Panel, at ./src/shared_library.c:99"

Tags: ros2, rviz, cmake, rviz-plugins

I have a package, inside which I have a .cpp and .hpp files for a custom rviz2 panel implementation. Currently, the most bare bones possible.

Everything compiles normaly. However, when I add the panel to RViz2, I get the following error:

`PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'rviz2_panel/Rviz2Panel' failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /home/lampa/Documents/TerraScout_Simulator/wp4_simulation/install/terrascout_simulation/lib/terrascout_simulation/librviz2_panel.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library dlopen error: /home/lampa/Documents/TerraScout_Simulator/wp4_simulation/install/terrascout_simulation/lib/terrascout_simulation/librviz2_panel.so: undefined symbol: _ZTV10Rviz2Panel, at ./src/shared_library.c:99`

I cant seem to figure out how to fix it. I feel. like there could be a problem with my Cmake or .xml files. But I can't seem to find it

The files are as follows:
rviz2_panel.cpp

```
Rviz2Panel::Rviz2Panel(QWidget* parent)
  : rviz_common::Panel(parent)
{
  // Create a button
  QPushButton * button = new QPushButton("Click Me!", this);

  // Connect button click signal to a slot
  connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClick()));

  // Create a layout for the panel
  QHBoxLayout * layout = new QHBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(button);

  // Set the panel layout
  setLayout(layout);
}

Rviz2Panel::~Rviz2Panel()
{

}
void Rviz2Panel::onButtonClick()
{
  // This function will be called when the button is clicked
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("custom panel"), "Button Clicked!");
}

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(Rviz2Panel, rviz_common::Panel)
```

rviz2_panel.hpp

```
class Rviz2Panel : public rviz_common::Panel
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Rviz2Panel(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

  virtual ~Rviz2Panel() override;

public Q_SLOTS:
  void onButtonClick();
};
```

rviz2_panel_description.xml

```
<library path="rviz2_panel">
  <class name="rviz2_panel/Rviz2Panel"
          type="Rviz2Panel"
          base_class_type="rviz_common::Panel">
    <description>
      Custom panel plugin
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

And lastly, CMakeLists.txt (The importatnt parts)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(terrascout_simulation)

# Default to C++17
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_components REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_action REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(vox_nav_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rviz_common REQUIRED)
find_package(pluginlib REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui)

...
# Rviz2 panel
add_library(rviz2_panel src/rviz2_panel.cpp include/terrascout_simulation/rviz2_panel.hpp)
target_include_directories(rviz2_panel PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_compile_features(rviz2_panel PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

target_link_libraries(rviz2_panel
  rclcpp::rclcpp
  rviz_common::rviz_common
  pluginlib::pluginlib
  Qt5::Core  
  Qt5::Widgets
  Qt5::Gui
)
  
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(rviz_common config/rviz2_panel_description.xml)

install(TARGETS rviz2_panel
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

install(
  DIRECTORY
    config
    launch
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which header files are you including? I also tried a bit to get mine working, I don't see any substantial differences in the xml or c++ files, but have some different things in the C

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  include/rviz_panel.hpp
  src/rviz_panel.cpp)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY AUTOMOC ON)

include_directories(include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
  ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Qt5Quick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ament_target_dependencies(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${THIS_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DEPENDS}
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "PLUGINLIB__DISABLE_BOOST_FUNCTIONS")

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib  
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_export_libraries(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
)
ament_export_targets(
  export_${PROJECT_NAME}
)

pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(rviz_common rviz_plugins.xml)
ament_package()
```